# Echo Nothing when Query is Empty

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check if the user input $entry is empty, and if it is, to echo nothing. I don't want it to do anything. There are no results, it shouldn't display anything. However, I keep getting an empty query error.

Here is my php:

```
$link = fConnectToDatabase();

//Retrieve parameters from querystring

$entry = fCleanString($link, $_GET['entry'], 15);


if (!empty($entry)) {

       $sql = "select price, name, image
       from geekproducts
       where name like  '%$entry%' or ' $entry '
       order by name";
       }

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
     or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));

if (! ($result)){
      echo "";
    }
```

How do I get my page to display nothing when the result is null?

**EDIT** The problem seems to be solely with

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
 or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
```

Getting rid of the or die statement returns a big paragraph on syntax errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to echo nothing? echoing nothing is doing nothing.. your last if clause is useless..

Comment: Yes, the last clause should be irrelevant. However when the query is empty, I get a SQL error saying the query is empty... I think it would be better for me to have said "I want the page to say there are no results".

Comment: or ' $entry ' is always true - as in SELECT 1 = 3 OR 2; -> TRUE

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if (isset($_GET['entry']) {
  $entry = fCleanString($link, $_GET['entry'], 15);
   $sql = "select price, name, image
   from geekproducts
   where name like  '%$entry%' or ' $entry '
   order by name";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
 or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
} else {
  echo 'nothing ;)';
}
```

Comment: I tried this, you're missing an extra paranthesis after `'entry'])` by the way. 

Instead I got an error saying mysqli_query is expecting a parameter and is receiving a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)echo '';
```

Comment: The same error appears:

Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in (myfile) on line 32 SQL syntax error
In which line 32 is: `$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
         or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link)).`

Comment: do you try to use `mysql_query` ?

Comment: I took the i out and received this (new, interesting!) message: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in line 32.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is suppressing the error

```
$link = fConnectToDatabase();

//Retrieve parameters from querystring

$entry = fCleanString($link, $_GET['entry'], 15);


if (!empty($entry)) {

   $sql = "select price, name, image
   from geekproducts
   where name like  '%$entry%' or ' $entry '
   order by name";
   }

$result = @mysqli_query($link, $sql)
```

Adding **@** before the function suppresses errors